# How to do a full site collecion level re-index in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

After adding a new managed property I need to do a full site collection level or tenant level re-indexing to get the search crawler run. But I could not find a way to do this in SharePoint online.Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the `Site Settings > Search and Offline Availability` link and then press the reindex option as in below image.

You need to be site collection admin or owner to view these settings:

[image]

[image]

**Updated as per comments:**

To trigger a full site collections reindex, you need to make use of PS script as in [this](https://www.techmikael.com/2014/02/how-to-trigger-full-re-index-in.html) link.

Comment: Thank you Gautam, I did this but unfortunately it only re-indexed the root site not the subsites in it. By the way is there a way to do this in tenant level since I have multiple site collections and those site collections have more than 100 subsites , It would be easy if I can re-index them at once.

Comment: hey @DarshaniJayasekara, have updated answer with a link to script which will help you trigger a reindex on site collection. However, SPO has continuous crawl enabled by default, and a full crawl usually every week, so your content should come up within couple of hours of posting it. No need to reindex it as SPO handles it very well usually.

Comment: Thanx Gautam for the PS script. Yes SPO has continuous cowling enabled. but in my situation i have added couple of new manged properties in search. So to get them crawled in next crawler have to re-index the site.

Comment: ok so in that case, just add list items to your list or files in doc lib and input the column values. It will be crawled. Happy to help ! 
If this answer helped you, you can accept it like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thanx, but here I am working on a spo tenant which has about ten site collections, each includes about 50 sub sites, so it is very difficult go each and every lists and add new items to get it crawled.Also this is a production tenant

Answer (score 1):

There is a script to re-index a SharePoint online site collection via CSOM. I think this will help you to re-index your 100+ subsites.

```
#Grab the tenant information 
$username = Read-Host "Enter the tenant admin account login" 

$password = Read-host -AsSecureString "Enter the admin account password" 

$siteUrl = Read-Host "Please enter the site collection URL to re-index"

Write-Host "Would you like to populate the managed properties on all lists post re-crawl (ex. Cross Site Publishing)?" -ForegroundColor Green

Write-Host "1. Yes - enable managed properties on all lists in this site!" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "2. No - Turn off managed properties in all lists in the site!" -ForegroundColor Blue
Write-Host "3. No - Just re-index the site!" -ForegroundColor Red
$enableAllManagedProperties = Read-Host "Choice [1-3]?"

$date = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd") 

#Load the assemblies 

$load1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$load2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$load3 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles")
if (!$load1) { 
    $script_folder = (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
    $load1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($script_folder + "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
    if (!$load1) { 
        Write-Host "Failed to load Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll - please ensure it is in the same location as the PS1." -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host "Alternatively, install the SPO Client Components SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038" -ForegroundColor Red 
        exit;
    }
}
if (!$load2) { 
    $script_folder = (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
    $load2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($script_folder + "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")
    if (!$load2) { 
        Write-Host "Failed to load Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll - please ensure it is in the same location as the PS1." -ForegroundColor Red 
        write-host "Alternatively, install the SPO Client Components SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038" -ForegroundColor Red
        exit;
    }
}
if (!$load3) { 
    $script_folder = (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
    $load3 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($script_folder + "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll")
    if (!$load3) { 
        Write-Host "Failed to load Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll - please ensure it is in the same location as the PS1." -ForegroundColor Red 
        write-host "Alternatively, install the SPO Client Components SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038" -ForegroundColor Red
        exit;
    }
}

function Connect-SPO($siteUrl) {
    $clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
    $clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 

    if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) { 
        Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: '$siteUrl'" -ForegroundColor Green 
    } 

    $rootWeb = $clientContext.Web
    processWeb($rootweb) 
}

function processWeb($web) {
    $subWebs = $web.Webs
    $clientContext.Load($web)  
    $clientContext.Load($web.AllProperties)
    $clientContext.Load($subWebs)
    try
    {
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    }
    catch
    {
        write-host "Error on $($clientContext) - $($_)" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "It's possible you are not an administrator on the site collection - Exiting the script" -ForegroundColor Red
        Sleep 10 
        Exit
    }


    Write-Host "Web URL:" $web.Url -ForegroundColor White
    if ( $enableAllManagedProperties -ne "3" ) {
        Set-AllManagedProperties -web $web -clientContext $clientContext -enableAllManagedProps $enableAllManagedProperties
    }

    [int]$version = 0
    $allProperties = $web.AllProperties
    if ( $allProperties.FieldValues.ContainsKey("vti_searchversion") -eq $true ) {
        $version = $allProperties["vti_searchversion"]
    }
    $version++
    $allProperties["vti_searchversion"] = $version
    Write-Host "-- Updated search version: " $version -ForegroundColor Green
    $web.Update()
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    # No need to process subwebs if we only mark site collection for indexing
    if ($enableAllManagedProperties -ne "3") {
        foreach ($subWeb in $subWebs) {
            processWeb($subWeb)
        }
    }
}

function Set-AllManagedProperties( $web, $clientContext, $enableAllManagedProps ) {
    $lists = $web.Lists
    $clientContext.Load($lists)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    foreach ($list in $lists) {
        Write-Host "--" $list.Title

        if ( $list.NoCrawl ) {
            Write-Host "--  Skipping list due to not being crawled" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            continue
        }

        $skip = $false;
        $eventReceivers = $list.EventReceivers
        $clientContext.Load($eventReceivers)
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        foreach ( $eventReceiver in $eventReceivers ) {
            if ( $eventReceiver.ReceiverClass -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CatalogEventReceiver" ) {
                $skip = $true
                Write-Host "--  Skipping list as it's published as a catalog" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                break
            }
        }
        if ( $skip ) {continue}

        $folder = $list.RootFolder
        $props = $folder.Properties
        $clientContext.Load($folder)  
        $clientContext.Load($props)
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        if ( $enableAllManagedProps -eq "1" ) {
            Write-Host "--  Enabling all managed properties" -ForegroundColor Green
            $props["vti_indexedpropertykeys"] = "UAB1AGIAbABpAHMAaABpAG4AZwBDAGEAdABhAGwAbwBnAFMAZQB0AHQAaQBuAGcAcwA=|SQBzAFAAdQBiAGwAaQBzAGgAaQBuAGcAQwBhAHQAYQBsAG8AZwA=|"
            $props["IsPublishingCatalog"] = "True"
        }
        if ( $enableAllManagedProps -eq "2" ) {
            Write-Host "--  Disabling all managed properties" -ForegroundColor Green
            $props["vti_indexedpropertykeys"] = $null
            $props["IsPublishingCatalog"] = $null
        }
        $folder.Update()
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()  
    }
}


#SPO Credentials 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $Password) 
Connect-SPO -siteUrl $siteurl

if ($version -ne "$null" ) {
Write-Host "Re-index has should now have been succesfully triggered for $siteurl - Please remember that this can take some time before the crawl picks up the index." -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Re-index-a-Sharepoint-e70d285b

**Note: This will not improve crawl time, merely ensure items are re-indexed.**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20631259)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Will update the answer with specific solution.